# TestNG for functional testing an API

Tags: rest, testing, testng, web-api-testing, operations-orchestration

I am tasked to write functional tests for an API and I am looking to use TestNG for it, is there a way I could orchestrate a bunch of API calls into one `@Test` - an example is `POST` on a resource, `GET` on the same resource based on the response from previous `POST`, then `PATCH` on the same resource using response from `GET` and then `DELETE` finally.

Could I do this in TestNG, any examples or snippets or pointers would be greatly helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

TestNG just runs tests. Use [REST Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured) to manage API calls.